# How can I make PDF's from SLDDRW files with Python

Tags: python, pdf, drawing, solidworks

My python level is beginner and this is what I would like to achieve:

I have multiple SLDDRW drawings that I want to convert to PDF. We have one person filling our ERP system and she doesn't have SolidWorks skills.

Is there a way to make PDF files from SLDDRW files with Python?

I tried opening the file, but I keep getting errors that it can't open the file.
I look at these three websites for reference, but could figure how to put that to use:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73880/Using-COM-Objects-in-Scripting-Languages-Part-2-Py
One is pastebin, but the code is so long with examples I will post in the comments for reference.
http://help.solidworks.com/2017/english/api/sldworksapi/save_file_as_pdf_example_vbnet.htm#_ga=2.166727292.314089170.1575624432-6e4601e0-9f07-11e9-9e64-2955c257ea75

Anybody got some clues on how to make this?

Thank you for responding!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/h68zSEUz

Comment: Could you provide some of your code or a MRE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example?

Comment: It's quite hard to get Solidworks working with Python. Any reason not to go with vba, vb.net or c#?

Comment: Knowledge at this point, to be honest.